# CSSグリッドでサイドメニュー固定を作ったが、サイドメニュー上でマウスをスクロールさせてもメインコンテンツ側がスクロールしない

Tags: html, css

下記のようにHTMLとCSSを作ってみました。
サイドメニュー上でマウスをスクロールさせ、サイドメニューが全部表示されている場合（もしくはサイドメニューを下までスクロールしきった場合）は、コンテンツ側をスクロールさせたいのですが、やりかたがわかりません。

なにか方法はないかと思って下記ページをみてみましたが、やはりサイドメニューとメインコンテンツ側は独立しており、サイドメニュー上でマウスをスクロールしたとしても、コンテンツ側がスクロールすることはありませんでした。

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48107353/allow-one-grid-item-to-scroll-with-fixed-header-and-sidebar
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58562531/css-grid-with-fixed-sidebar

一方、CSSグリッドを使用しない以下の方法はサイドメニュー上でマウスをスクロールするとコンテンツ側がスクロールして内容を下部まで表示することができました。

- https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_sidenav_fixed2
- https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_sidenav_fixed

違いはなんなのでしょうか？CSSグリッドでは不可能なのでしょうか？それとも何かアプローチの仕方が違うのでしょうか？

```css
.mainSpace {
    min-height: 100vh;
    display: grid;
    grid-template: 
        "a-side a-body" 100vh
    /   320px 1fr;
}
.mainSpaceSide {
    grid-area: a-side;
    background-color: yellow;
    overflow: scroll;
}
.mainSpaceBody {
    grid-area: a-body;
    background-color: green;
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div class="mainSpace">
    <div class="mainSpaceSide">
        start side<br>
        side<br>side<br>side<br>side<br>side<br>side<br>side<br>side<br>side<br>
        side<br>side<br>side<br>side<br>side<br>side<br>side<br>side<br>side<br>
        end side
    </div>
    <div class="mainSpaceBody">
        start main<br>
        main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>
        main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>
        main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>
        main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>
        main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>
        end main
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

ひとつの方法は、**スクロール連鎖**を利用するものです。スクロール連鎖とは、あるスクロールコンテナをスクロールし境界に達したとき、当該スクロールコンテナの祖先となるスクロールコンテナへスクロールが伝播することです。

今回の場合は、 `.mainSpace` を祖先スクロールコンテナ、 `.mainSpaceSide` を子孫スクロールコンテナとします。そして `.mainSpaceBody` をスクロールコンテナとせず、 `.mainSpaceSide` のスクロールイベントを `.mainSpace` へ伝播させます。するとスクロール連鎖によって、 `.mainSpaceSide` のスクロール境界に達したとき、あたかも `.mainSpaceBody` がスクロールするかのような動作を実現出来ます。

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.mainSpace {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  grid-template: "a-side a-body" 100vh / 320px 1fr;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: green;
}

.mainSpaceSide {
  grid-area: a-side;
  background-color: yellow;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}

.mainSpaceBody {
  grid-area: a-body;
}
```

```html
<div class="mainSpace">
  <div class="mainSpaceSide">
    start side<br> side
    <br>side<br>side<br>side<br>side<br>side<br>side<br>side<br>side<br> side
    <br>side<br>side<br>side<br>side<br>side<br>side<br>side<br>side<br> end side
  </div>
  <div class="mainSpaceBody">
    start main<br> main
    <br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br> main
    <br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br> main
    <br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br> main
    <br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br> main
    <br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br> end main
  </div>
</div>
```

---

もうひとつの方法は、 JavaScript を用いてスクロールする対象を制御するものです。ただし、 `scroll` イベントは「ページの一番上や下から、さらに上や下へスクロールしようとしたとき」のように、そもそもスクロールが発生しないような場合には**発火しません**。このため、ここでは **`wheel` イベントを使う**必要がある点に注意が必要です。さらに、 `WheelEvent.deltaY` 属性が必ずしもスクロールの方向を示すわけではない点にも注意を払う必要があります。

```js
const mainSpaceSide = document.querySelector(".mainSpace > .mainSpaceSide");
const mainSpaceBody = document.querySelector(".mainSpace > .mainSpaceBody");
const scrollLength = 100;

mainSpaceSide.addEventListener(
  "wheel",
  function(e) {
    const direction = e.deltaY;
    if (direction < 0 && mainSpaceSide.scrollTop <= 0) {
      mainSpaceBody.scrollTo({
        top: mainSpaceBody.scrollTop - scrollLength,
        behavior: "smooth"
      });
    } else if (direction > 0 && (mainSpaceSide.scrollHeight - mainSpaceSide.scrollTop === mainSpaceSide.clientHeight)) {
      mainSpaceBody.scrollTo({
        top: mainSpaceBody.scrollTop + scrollLength,
        behavior: "smooth"
      });
    }
  }
);
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.mainSpace {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  grid-template: "a-side a-body" 100vh / 320px 1fr;
}

.mainSpaceSide {
  grid-area: a-side;
  background-color: yellow;
  overflow: scroll;
}

.mainSpaceBody {
  grid-area: a-body;
  background-color: green;
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div class="mainSpace">
  <div class="mainSpaceSide">
    start side<br> side
    <br>side<br>side<br>side<br>side<br>side<br>side<br>side<br>side<br> side
    <br>side<br>side<br>side<br>side<br>side<br>side<br>side<br>side<br> end side
  </div>
  <div class="mainSpaceBody">
    start main<br> main
    <br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br> main
    <br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br> main
    <br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br> main
    <br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br> main
    <br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br>main<br> end main
  </div>
</div>
```